# How lo create a dataset from files with different formats in azure ML studio

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

I trying to load the data from the [kaggle M5](https://www.kaggle.com/c/m5-forecasting-accuracy) competition to AZ ML Studio

Which contains the following files:

[image]

I extracted them in a folder in my machine and used the GUI to upload the complete folder as an ML Studio dataset:

[image]

[image]

The problem is that is identifying only one schema of one of the files

[image]

Which is to corrected way to work with this kind of datasets? should I load each file independently as a dataset or is there a way of handle several files in the same dataset?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to load independently. There is a chance to merge all the files from one path with CSV extension

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'~/Downloads'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
all_files
```

If your files have any series of numbers in file names. Use the following code block

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd

path = "/home/user/data/"

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "data_*.csv"))
```

Combine all the files into one list and export as CSV

```
df_merged = (pd.read_csv(f, sep=',') for f in all_files)
df_merged   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
df_merged.to_csv( "merged.csv")
```

The implementation looks like below image and check the respective [link](https://softhints.com/how-to-merge-multiple-csv-files-with-python/#:%7E:text=Steps%20to%20merge%20multiple%20CSV%20%28identical%29%20files%20with,files%20in%20the%20list%20and%20export%20as%20CSV) for the reference and complete documentation.

[image]